# Páginas de error no traducidas

Tags: característica-nueva

Apenas llegué a una página de error: 
http://stackexchange.com/leagues/381/week/es-stackoverflow

¿Tendremos páginas de error personalizadas o se usarán las versiones en inglés?
A mí me gustarían personalizadas en texto y en gráficos.

La página sale como link en la parte baja de la pantalla [moderadores](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators) dentro de usuarios

Comment: Creo que esa página que enlazas no debe ser traducida ya que es del sitio *padre* (¿?) StackExchange. Las traducciones solo deberían ser aplicables al los sitios *hijos* según corresponda.

Answer (score 2):

Considero que en un futuro todas las páginas deberían estar traducidas al español, hay que ver un ejemplo del sitio actual en portugués:

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1019elenasys404/

Creo que podríamos ayudar a @JuanM a ayudar la traducción de estas páginas y porque no proponer imagen!